# Google wifi connection logs?

Tags: nest

I received copyright infringement notice from a law firm, a alleging downloading of copyrighted material from a client on my home network. It includes the visited website+timestamp.

I need to find out, which client/device is responsible. How to find that out? Are there logs or other functionality that i can use? We are using the Google wifi mesh network.